# Does ext4 support execute-in-place?

Tags: linux, ext4

ext2 supposedly supported this functionality. NTFS and AXFS both support it. Does ext4 have the ability to execute-in-place?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia's Comparison of File Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Features) the answer is *yes*.

A [lwn.net artice](http://lwn.net/Articles/610174/) sheds some more light on it, essentially that *XIP* (execute-in-place) is replaced by *DAX* (direct access).

This commit introduced DAX functionality for ext4 into the Linux kernel, and hence it should be included in kernel versions `>= 4.0`:

> ```
> commit 923ae0ff9250430133b3310fe62c47538cf1cbc1
> Refs: v3.19-6697-g923ae0f
> Author: Ross Zwisler <ross.zwisler@linux.intel.com>
> Date:   Mon Feb 16 15:59:38 2015 -0800
>
> ext4: add DAX functionality
> This is a port of the DAX functionality found in the current version of ext2.
> ```

Comment: I don't see any citation for it. DAX was said to not be be like XIP.

Comment: @Melab: I interpreted the following passage as "DAX replaces XIP": `Matthew Wilcox began work on improving the XIP code and integrating it into the ext4 filesystem. (...) over time, his work shifted from enhancing XIP to replacing it. (...) Those patches replace the XIP code with a new subsystem called DAX (...)`. I neither use XIP, nor DAX, so I can be wrong.